# Create a two-dimensional array in Solidity

Tags: solidity, dapps

How to create arrays addresses using solidity? And we can write two-dimensional array?

```
bool[2][] m_pairsOfFlags;
```

Here is an example of the array, but it does not work

Comment: This might help mapping (uint256 => mapping (uint256 => bool)) m_pairsOfFlags;

Comment: the example you are talking about is in the official documentation : 
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html

So what do you exactly mean by does not work?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes you can.

This little snippet might help. It's just a little toy to show how the two-dimensional array elements are referenced.

It might be helpful to point out that things may be a little counter-intuitive because the X & Y axis may seem to be reversed.

```
bool[2][] flags;
```

It starts by describing a length 2 array of bools. Then it goes on to say there will be a dynamic *list of those* called `flags`.

So, to reference such things, the dynamic dimension is high order.

```
bool flag = flags[dynamicIndex][lengthTwoIndex];
```

The above might look backwards, so that can be disorienting.

Some functions I put together to demo this in [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;

// set all the inserts to true for simplicity

contract Arrays{
    
    // dynamic list of length 2 bools
    bool[2][] flags;
    
    function Arrays() {
        // append a length 2 array to the dynamic list of flags
        flags.push([true,true]);
    }
    
    function appendFlag() returns(uint length) {
       // append another length 2 array to the dynamic dimension
       return flags.push([true,true]);
    }
    
    // return a length 2 array stored in the dynamic dimension
    // will throw if index > flags.length-1 (index starts at 0)
    function getFlags(uint index) constant returns(bool[2] flagList) {
        return(flags[index]);
    }
    
    // return one flag from the array
    function getFlag(uint dynamicIndex, uint lengthTwoIndex) constant returns(bool flag) {
        return flags[dynamicIndex][lengthTwoIndex];
    }
    
    // return a count of length 2 arrays stored in flags;
    function getFlagsCount() constant returns(uint count) {
        return flags.length;
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Was it a design choice of solidity to reverse the indexes or is it a bug that will be fixed later (or never cuz we're stuck with it)?

Comment: It's a design choice.