# How to update/insert data into the cell in 2-dimensional array?

Tags: solidity, arrays

Sir,

When I execute assignment statement in order to insert/update int value to one cell in 2-dimensional array,it doesn't succeed.
The geth console didn't response any error message.The contract just return 0.

My contract is like below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
contract MemDeposit
{
   struct deposit {
   string[] ss_ids;  
   int[][] si_deposit;
}
mapping(address=>deposit) private si_md;  
.......

function addMemDeposit(address p_memacct,string p_acctstr,uint p_idx2,int p_money) external returns(int) {
   int li_idx1;
   li_idx1 = 0 ; //just for test
   ...
   si_md[p_memacct].si_deposit[p_idx2][li_idx1] = p_money; //this doesn't work,contract quit here,client get 0
   ...

   }

}
```

I have debug this contract,the error occurs in the assign statement.So my question is how to insert(or update) data to the cell in 2-dimensional array?

Sincerely!

Barkely

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your array before updating values in it.

When you call `addMemDeposit(p_memacct, ...)` with fresh `p_memmacct`, this code:

```
si_md[p_memacct].si_deposit
```

implicitly creates a new instance of `deposit` struct. And this instance is empty. This means that `ss_ids` is an empty array and `si_deposit` is an empty array.

But in this line, you are trying to update nonexistent value in an empty array:

```
si_md[p_memacct].si_deposit[p_idx2][li_idx1] = p_money;
```

Try to init `si_deposit` before updating it. For example:

```
function initMemDeposit(address p_memacct) {
    si_md[p_memacct].si_deposit = [[int(1), 2, 3]];
}
```

Check [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11870/create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-solidity) for more info on two-dimensional arrays.